# CodeIgniter getting username and display it from Model to View

Tags: php, codeigniter

After a few testing here and there, I have finally found a way where I can get the registered username. But I still can't make it to display on the page. I am stuck at getting the value from Model to Controller.

Below are my codes:

**Model (user_model):**

```
public function create_user( $role, $insert_array = array() )
{
if( ! empty( $insert_array ) OR $this->validate() === TRUE )
            {
                ...

            // Verify transaction was successful
            if( $this->db->trans_status() !== FALSE )
            {
                // Load var to confirm user inserted into database
                $this->load->vars( array( 'user_created' => 1 ) );
                $reg_username = $user_data['user_name'];
            }

            return TRUE;
        }
return FALSE;
    }
```

**View:**

```
if( isset( $validation_passed ) && $reg_mode == 1 )
    {

        echo '
            <div class="feedback confirmation">
                <p>
                    Thank you for registering. Your new username is :  You may now ' . secure_anchor('user', 'login') . '.
                </p>
            </div>
        ';
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
$this->load->model('user_model');
$this->user_model->create_user( 'customer', array() );
```

What and how should I do it?

Appreciate if you guys can help me out on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `echo $this->formval_callbacks->_username_check();` you're not passing the $user_name to the function

Comment: You better load your model in controller, then pass value to view with variable :P

Comment: Thanks guys for the help but I am so confused. My register page in Controllers has only 2 lines. I have updated my code in the question. The previous code for the model is actually the checking of the username when input in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any arguments to your function when calling in view

Instead of this

```
echo $this->formval_callbacks->_username_check(); // no arguments passed
```

Try

```
echo $this->formval_callbacks->_username_check('Bob'); // Bob is just an example username given
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question. I have finally managed to get the registered username but I am still unable to display it on the page no matter how I do it. I am stuck where I can't get the value from Model to Controller.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a view from your controller, then use can pass an associative array as a 2nd parameter to the view. The values in the array then become variables in the view.

In the controller

```
    $this->load->model('required_model');
    $user_data = $this->required_model->get_user_info();

//This should return an associative array from your model
//$user_data['username'] = username;
//$user_data['other_data'] = other_data;

    $this->load->view('required_view',$user_data);
```

Inside your view, use the variable $username and $otherdata to display the information.